# IHttpClientFactory in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I wanted to use `IHttpClientFactory` in my .NET Core project. The problem is that there are bulk of APIs that I need to consume. So should I use a single Typed Client for all the API's or should bifurcate those? All the API requests are to the same source.

```
public interface IStudentClient
{

}

public class StudentClient : IStudentClient
{

}

services.AddHttpClient<IStudentClient, StudentClient>();
```

I have followed the above structure and was planning to include all the API's inside `IStudentClient` and implement those in `StudentClient`. Now my question is, won't this will make the `StudentClient` more complex class when including all the API's implementation in only one class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion writing one big typed client for all the access to a specific remote service is the right way to go. That's exactly the usage pattern envisioned by Microsoft for the typed http client.

At the same time I understand your concern, but the situation il less desperate than you might think it to be.

First of all you will get a huge interface and, consequently, a huge implementing class, but the responsibility of them is clear: the typed client has the responsibility of defining a proxy to access a remote web service (the student service in your example).

The typed client class isn't indeed complex: it can be huge, for sure, but it's stateless and just exposes methods to access the endpoints of the remote web service. Each method has a clear and well defined responsibility: accessing a specific endpoint on the remote web service; code like that is rarely complicated.

The only concern is consuming the interface `IStudentClient` from a controller or a service. The interface is huge, so if you inject it as a dependency in a consumer class you will violate the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). A possible solution for this problem is modeling smaller interfaces, shaped for the specific needs of the consumer classes.

Imagine that one of the endpoints exposed by your remote web service lets you get the details for a single student (it could be something like GET /students/{studentId}). This means that one of the methods exposed by `IStudentClient` will be `GetStudentById(Guid studentId)` which wraps the GET request to `/students/{studentId}`.

At this point you can define a smaller interface called `IStudentProvider`, shaped like this:

```
public interface IStudentProvider
{
  StudentContract GetstudentById(Guid studentId);
}
```

Now you can inject the smaller interface `IStudentProvider` in your consumer classes (for example an MVC controller or a service class that you define in your application).

To implement the interface `IStudentProvider` you can do the following:

```
public class HttpStudentProvider : IStudentProvider 
{
  private readonly IStudentClient client;

  public HttpStudentProvider(IStudentClient client)
  {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public StudentContract GetstudentById(Guid studentId) 
  {
    return this.client.GetStudentById(studentId);
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT DISCLAIMER**: in order to keep the discussion simple I didn't use the `Task` class on the interfaces, but of course all of the methods should return `Task<T>` and accepts an instance of `CancellationToken` as a parameter, because http calls are natural asynchronous operations and you do **not** want to perform blocking calls with your http client.

**How to register these classes on the DI container**

The Microsoft DI container will offer you some extension methods to register a typed client. The service will be registered as a transient dependency, so each other service depending on it must be registered as a transient dependency too (in order to avoid the [captive dependency issue](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)).

This is the way you should register your services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHttpClient<IStudentClient, StudentClient>();
   services.AddTransient<IStudentProvider, HttpStudentProvider>();
}
```

Comment: ok. So for every different module, I should create a different interface? Then inject those in startup.cs file, like services.AddHttpClient<IStudentClient, StudentClient>(); and services.AddHttpClient<IStudentProvider , HttpStudentProvider >();

Comment: @Sunny I edited my response with some guidelines for the registration part of the story

Comment: Then do I need to initialize IStudentProvider in the main controller when I need to call GetstudentById() like private readonly IStudentProvider _studentProvider ;
        public HomeController(IStudentProvider studentProvider )
        {
            _studentProvider= studentProvider ;
        } or initializing IStudentClient only is enough?

Comment: @Sunny yes your classes should depend on the interface `IStudentProvider`, so you should inject an instance of `IStudentProvider` in the controller constructor.